# Rock Paper Scissors Game event listener

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a Rock Paper Scissors Game. I am stuck on my event listener function. I was able to make this display my image to show what the player chose, I want to add my playRound function to this event as well so that it runs the game when the button is clicked. Is it a bad idea to try and nest a function within this function?

```js
//Button Click Event Listener to Display Choice//
rock.addEventListener('click', function() {
  playerSign.getElementsByClassName('?')[0]
  playerSign.innerHTML = '<img src="./images/Rock.png" alt="Rock"/>'
});

paper.addEventListener('click', function() {
  playerSign.getElementsByClassName('?')[0]
  playerSign.innerHTML = '<img src="./images/Paper.png" alt="Paper"/>'
});

scissors.addEventListener('click', function() {
  playerSign.getElementsByClassName('?')[0]
  playerSign.innerHTML = '<img src="./images/Scissors.png" alt="Scissors"/>'
});


//Play Round//
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
    roundWinner = 'tie'
  }
  if (
    (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors') ||
    (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper') ||
    (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock')
  ) {
    playerScore++
    roundWinner = 'player'
  }
  if (
    (computerSelection === 'rock' && playerSelection === 'scissors') ||
    (computerSelection === 'scissors' && playerSelection === 'paper') ||
    (computerSelection === 'paper' && playerSelection === 'rock')
  ) {
    computerScore++
    roundWinner = 'computer'
  }
  updateScoreMessage(roundWinner, playerSelection, computerSelection)
}

function updateScore() {
  if (roundWinner === 'tie') {
    scoreMessage.textContent = "It's a tie!"
  } else if (roundWinner === 'player') {
    scoreMessage.textContent = 'You won!'
  } else if (roundWinner === 'computer') {
    scoreMessage.textContent = 'You lost!'
  }

  //Display choices for computer selection//

  computerSign.getElementsByClassName('?')[0]
  computerSign.innerHTML = '<img src="./images/Paper.png" alt="Paper"/>'

  //Random choice for Computer selection//
  function getRandomChoice() {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
    switch (randomNumber) {
      case 0:
        return 'rock'
      case 1:
        return 'paper'
      case 2:
        return 'scissors'
    }
  }
  //Computer selection function//
  const computerSelection = getRandomChoice()
  playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)
  updateChoices(playerSelection, computerSelection)
  updateScore()

  if (isGameOver()) {
    openEndgameModal()
    setFinalMessage()
  }
}

function updateChoices(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  switch (playerSelection) {
    case 'rock':
      playerSign.textContent = ''
      break
    case 'paper':
      playerSign.textContent = ''
      break
    case 'scissors':
      playerSign.textContent = ''
      break
  }

  switch (computerSelection) {
    case 'rock':
      computerSign.getElementsByClassName('?')[0]
      computerSign.innerHTML = '<img src="./images/Rock.png" alt="Rock"/>'
      break
    case 'paper':
      computerSign.getElementsByClassName('?')[0]
      computerSign.innerHTML = '<img src="./images/Paper.png" alt="Paper"/>'
      break
    case 'scissors':
      computerSign.getElementsByClassName('?')[0]
      computerSign.innerHTML = '<img src="./images/Scissors.png" alt="Scissors"/>'
      break
  }
}

//Update Score Message//

function updateScoreMessage(winner, playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (winner === 'player') {
    scoreMessage.textContent = `${capitalizeFirstLetter(
      playerSelection
    )} beats ${computerSelection.toLowerCase()}`
    return
  }
  if (winner === 'computer') {
    scoreMessage.textContent = `${capitalizeFirstLetter(
      playerSelection
    )} is beaten by ${computerSelection.toLowerCase()}`
    return
  }

  scoreMessage.textContent = `${capitalizeFirstLetter(
    playerSelection
  )} ties with ${computerSelection.toLowerCase()}`
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/rcz1ikf.css">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4c536a6bd5.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header class="heading">
    <h1>ROCK PAPER SCISSORS</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="rps">
    <h2>CHOOSE YOUR WEAPON</h2>
    <h3 class="score-message" id="scoreMessage">
      FIRST TO SCORE 5 POINTS WINS THE GAME</h3>
    </h3>
  </div>

  <div class="score-container">
    <div class="score-box">
      <div class="sign" id="playerSign">❔</div>
      <h2 class="score" id="playerScore">PLAYER:0</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="score-box">
      <div class="sign" id="computerSign">❔</div>
      <h2 class="computerScore">COMPUTER:0</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="button-box">
    <input type="image" src="./images/Rock.png" id="rockBtn">
    <input type="image" src="./images/Paper.png" id="paperBtn">
    <input type="image" src="./images/Scissors.png" id="scissorsBtn">
  </div>

</body>

<footer>
  COPYRIGHT &copy
  <script>
    new Date().getFullYear() > 2010 && document.write(+new Date().getFullYear());
  </script> NAME
  <! -- github icon --!>
  <a href="https://github.com/USERNAME" target="_blank">
    <i class="fab fa-github">
      </i>
  </a>
</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem is likely your `getElementsByClassName('?')` class.  Can you post some html that shows what classes you're working with?  To answer your question about nested functions, functions can call other functions its no big deal.

Comment: Thank you for responding, yes I can do that!

Comment: Thanks, you have a repeating `</h3>` termination you'll want to remove.  I'll take a look at the rest now.

Comment: I've turned your code in to a snippet. Did you provide all the necessary code for it to work?

Comment: Thank you for that, did not know how to turn it into a snippet. I added the rest of my js, I am still working on some of the functions but that is what I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In order to avoid "blah blah is undefined" console errors you'll need to create references for rock, paper, and scissors elements.
- Since none of these buttons have classes, referencing them by their ID using `getElementById()` will be what you need.
- In the event listener for each button, I added a line that calls your `playRound()` function, and sends it the choices for comparison.  Notice within this call, I can also pull the computer choice by calling `getRandomChoice()` for the second variable I'm sending to `playRound()`.
- While you CAN opt to ignore the trailing semicolon it is generally viewed as lazy and reduces readability.  Recommendation is to always specify the end of statements with a trailing semicolon.

Since `roundWinner` is not a globally defined variable it will need to be passed into the `updateScore()` function.  Since logically every time you play a round, it make sense to do this from within the `playRound()` function using `updateScore(roundWinner);`

- added `updateScore(roundWinner);` to the `playRound()` function.
- I've also added scoreMessage to the list above of defined elements.
- added some logging for debug

For keeping score I added a `data-score` attribute to the `computerScore` and `playerScore` elements.  Obviously you it would be easy to cheat the game this way but you could throw in some validation or keep those scores as globals.  Either way you'll need a way to retain the progress between games.

- added a first letter capitalization function because I don't have access to whatever {} you're doing.
- removed `updateScore()` and added that little bit of work into `playRound()`  It also appeared that `updateScore()` and `updateScoreMessage()` were both attempting to manipulate the same strings on the screen, possibly overwriting each other.

```js
const rock = document.getElementById("rockBtn");
const paper = document.getElementById("paperBtn");
const scissors = document.getElementById("scissorsBtn");
const playerSign = document.getElementById("playerSign");
const scoreMessage = document.getElementById("scoreMessage");
const pScore = document.getElementById("playerScore");
const cScore = document.getElementById("computerScore");

rock.addEventListener('click', function() {
  playerSign.innerHTML = '<img src="./images/Rock.png" alt="Rock"/>';
  playRound('rock', getRandomChoice());
});

paper.addEventListener('click', function() {
  playerSign.innerHTML = '<img src="./images/Paper.png" alt="Paper"/>';
  playRound('paper', getRandomChoice());
});

scissors.addEventListener('click', function() {
  playerSign.innerHTML = '<img src="./images/Scissors.png" alt="Scissors"/>';
  playRound('scissors', getRandomChoice());
});

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {

  if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
    roundWinner = 'tie';
  }

  if (
    (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors') ||
    (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper') ||
    (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock')
  ) {
    pScore.dataset.score = parseInt(pScore.dataset.score) + 1;
    pScore.textContent = "PLAYER:" + pScore.dataset.score;
    roundWinner = 'player';
  }
  if (
    (computerSelection === 'rock' && playerSelection === 'scissors') ||
    (computerSelection === 'scissors' && playerSelection === 'paper') ||
    (computerSelection === 'paper' && playerSelection === 'rock')
  ) {
    cScore.dataset.score = parseInt(cScore.dataset.score) + 1;
    cScore.textContent = "COMPUTER:" + cScore.dataset.score;
    roundWinner = 'computer';
  }
  console.log("Computer: " + computerSelection + ", Player: " + playerSelection + ", Winner: " + roundWinner + ".");
  updateScoreMessage(roundWinner, playerSelection, computerSelection);
}

function getRandomChoice() {
  let computerSign = document.getElementById("computerSign");
  let rndChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  var txtChoice;
  switch (rndChoice) {
    case 0:
      computerSign.innerHTML = '<img src="./images/Rock.png" alt="Rock"/>';
      txtChoice = 'rock';
      break;
    case 1:
      computerSign.innerHTML = '<img src="./images/Paper.png" alt="Paper"/>';
      txtChoice = 'paper';
      break;
    case 2:
      computerSign.innerHTML = '<img src="./images/Scissors.png" alt="Scissors"/>';
      txtChoice = 'scissors';
      break;
  }
  return txtChoice;
}

function updateScoreMessage(winner, playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  var txtMessage = '';
  if (winner === 'player') {
    scoreMessage.textContent = 'You win! Selection: ' + flCapital(playerSelection) + ' beats ' + flCapital(computerSelection) + '!';
    return;
  }
  if (winner === 'computer') {
    scoreMessage.textContent = 'You lose! Selection: ' + flCapital(computerSelection) + ' beats ' + flCapital(playerSelection) + '!';
    return;
  }
  scoreMessage.textContent = 'Your selection: ' + flCapital(playerSelection) + ' ties with ' + flCapital(computerSelection) + '!';
}

function flCapital(str) {
  if (!str) return;
  return str.match("^[a-z]") ? str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1) : str;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/rcz1ikf.css">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4c536a6bd5.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <header class="heading">
      <h1>ROCK PAPER SCISSORS</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="rps">
      <h2>CHOOSE YOUR WEAPON</h2>
      <h3 class="score-message" id="scoreMessage">
        FIRST TO SCORE 5 POINTS WINS THE GAME
      </h3>
    </div>

    <div class="score-container">
      <div class="score-box">
        <div class="sign" id="playerSign">❔</div>
        <!-- added data-score attribute -->
        <h2 class="score" id="playerScore" data-score="0">PLAYER:0</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="score-box">
        <div class="sign" id="computerSign">❔</div>
        <!-- added data-score attribute -->
        <h2 class="score" id="computerScore" data-score="0">COMPUTER:0</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button-box">
      <input type="image" src="./images/Rock.png" id="rockBtn">
      <input type="image" src="./images/Paper.png" id="paperBtn">
      <input type="image" src="./images/Scissors.png" id="scissorsBtn">
    </div>

  </body>

  <footer>
    COPYRIGHT &copy; <script>
      new Date().getFullYear() > 2010 && document.write(+new Date().getFullYear());

    </script> NAME
    <! -- github icon --!>
      <a href="https://github.com/USERNAME" target="_blank">
        <i class="fab fa-github">
        </i>
      </a>
  </footer>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wqmzyk67/4/

Comment: Wow, thank you! This resolved the issue I was having! I also learned a lot from your revision. I really appreciate your explanation as well!

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that you write:

```
rock.addEventListener('click', function() {
```

but you never defined what 'rock' is. you miss to add the const/variable definition for rock, paper and scissors to go on.

```
const rock = getElementById('rockBtn')
```

and so on